# What ways a website could hack a device?

Tags: web-browser, url, code-execution, drive-by-download

Is it possible that clicking a link would hack a device?

For example:

- injecting a malicious code into the device directly from the link's host website
- connecting to the device remotely in a way through its internet connection

And how to protect a device from them?

Comment: Links do nothing. The site you connect to does.

Comment: Short answer: code on the site exploits a vulnerability in the browser.